# VM: Mac OSX Host, Windows Guest: Use VT-d so that the fast GPU is available for the VM?

Tags: macos, virtualbox, virtual-machine, gpu, vt-d

Vt-d is enabled in recent MacBook Pros, but I did not find any information on actual gpu sharing.

Is it possible to set up a MacBook Pro with two GPUs (Intel, nVidia or AMD) so that I can use the fast GPU in a windows guest for graphics development or gaming?

[Parallels Extreme (wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallels_Workstation_Extreme) offers a solution for Windows/Linux, but I would like to use a Mac as a host.

Answer (score 2):

PCI passthrough need to be supported by both hardware and software. Most of current Macs support VT-d in hardware, but as of now (High Sierra) Apple does not support IOMMU in macOS, making it impossible to use PCI devices (including GPUs) in guest OS directly.

You can install Linux or Windows host OS on MacBook, and use GPU in virtualised OS, but this is probably not what you are looking for.